# Inline-block not vertically aligning div-elements correctly

Tags: vertical-alignment, css

I've got a problem with Chrome.

I'm trying to vertically-align some `div`elements using `display: inline-block;`
instead of floating them. The problem occurs when I put some text into them: for a strange reason, Chrome displays differently filled `divs` onto different lines.

Firefox and IE are working correctly.
For better understanding check [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/pHCSx/11/)

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to add for global wrapper `font-size: 0;` and set regular font size for your inline blocks, you can also add: `letter-spacing: 0;` and `word-spacing: 0;`, something like this:

```
.wrapper {
  font-size: 0;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  word-spacing: 0;
}

  .wrapper .inline_block {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    word-spacing: .1em;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
```

and example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ab22/
and updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ab22/3/

Comment: I did as you suggested. For the first 3 elements the problem was fixed, but not for the last ones.
Here, have a look
http://jsfiddle.net/pHCSx/14/

Comment: if you have some margins or paddings add rule for `:last-child` and reset them

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not because of any padding or margin :(
Here as you can see in your example there is the same problem
http://jsfiddle.net/3ab22/2/

Even changing the font-family does change the behaviour of the DIVs position. I just can't figure out why is this appening.

Comment: Exactly, the vertical-align did the trick!! :)
I found the solution myself but couldn't answer the question because I'm still newbie in here.
Anyway thanks for your help!